# heroku web crashes

Tags: heroku

So I'm following the tutorial in this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#deploy-to-heroku

once i do "heroku ps" i get:

```
=== web: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
web.1: crashed 2013/02/18 20:22:37 (~ 8m ago)
```

I don't exactly understand what is the problem here, can someone help? am i suppose to have my Procfile where manage.py is? I tried to move it over to there, but the same error still shows up.

btw my logs are:

```
2013-02-19T04:36:22+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by deathlordx87@yahoo.com
2013-02-19T04:41:14+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by deathlordx87@yahoo.com
2013-02-19T04:43:10+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-02-19T04:43:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py      runserver 0.0.0.0:31831 --noreload`
2013-02-19T04:43:18+00:00 app[web.1]: python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2013-02-19T04:43:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2013-02-19T04:43:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-02-19T04:44:05+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by deathlordx87@yahoo.com
```

Comment: try searching the logs `heroku logs`

Comment: my logs are there, but i still dont know what i did wrong

Comment: Start troubleshooting this error: `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem once. You need to configure your settings.py file properly. Since Heroku doesn't support sqlite3 databases so you should check that the database portion of the settings.py file is configured correctly.

Check my minimal sample app successfully deployed to Heroku https://github.com/shinigamiryuk/Django-Heroku-Sample-Application

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The log line `can't open file 'manage.py'` suggests that the file is missing or can't be found. Did you add manage.py to your git depo before deploying to heroku? Is manage.py stored in a different directory from your Procfile/where the program runs?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your project (if it follows the *Two Scoops* layout) has manage.py inside a project directory and not in your repository root.

To keep this layout, create a `Procfile` and within it script a directory change before running gunicorn.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619886/is-it-possible-to-have-a-procfile-and-a-manage-py-file-in-a-different-folder-lev/25284938#25284938) for an example.