# Is it possible to have a Procfile and a manage.py file in a different folder level?

Tags: django, heroku, directory, virtualenv, procfile

## **Introduction:**

- I am following the [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) quick start guide.
- I intend to apply the *Two Scoops of Django* book philosophy about working with virtualenvs and projects. *Audrey Roy* and *Daniel Greenfeld* (authors) like to put all the environments in one directory and all the projects in another.
- I also intend to apply the *Two Scoops of Django* book philosophy about placing what is generated by the `django-admin.py startproject` management command **inside another directory which serves as the git repository root** (a.k.a. **three-tiered approach**).

The layout at the highest level:

```
repository_root/
    django_project_root/
        configuration_root/
```

## **Locally:**

OS X 10.8.4
pip==1.4.1
virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
.bashrc contains:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Projects
```

~/Envs
~/Projects

## **Inside hellodjango_venv:**

Django==1.5.2
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
static==0.4

## **From Terminal:**

```
mac-pol:~ oubiga$ mkdir -p Projects/hellodjango_rep/hellodjango
mac-pol:~ oubiga$ cd Projects/hellodjango_rep/hellodjango
mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ mkvirtualenv hellodjango_venv
New python executable in hellodjango_venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in hellodjango_venv/bin/python
Installing Setuptools..................................

...

..................................................done.
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ pip install django-toolbelt

...

Successfully installed django-toolbelt django psycopg2 gunicorn dj-database-url dj-static static
Cleaning up...
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ touch Procfile && open Procfile
```

Edit Procfile:

`web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`

Start the process:

```
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ foreman start
01:30:37 web.1  | started with pid 638
01:30:37 web.1  | 2013-09-04 01:30:37 [638] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
01:30:37 web.1  | 2013-09-04 01:30:37 [638] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (638)
01:30:37 web.1  | 2013-09-04 01:30:37 [638] [INFO] Using worker: sync
01:30:37 web.1  | 2013-09-04 01:30:37 [641] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 641
CTRL+C
```

So far, so good.

At the moment my Projects tree is:

```
~/Projects/    
    hellodjango_rep/
        hellodjango/ cwd
            manage.py
            Procfile
            hellodjango/
                __init__.py
                settings/
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
```

and my Virtualenvs tree is:

```
~/Envs/
    get_env_details
    initialize
    postactivate
    postdeactivate
    postmkproject
    postmkvirtualenv
    postrmproject
    postrmvirtualenv
    preactivate
    predeactivate
    premkproject
    premkvirtualenv
    prermproject
    prermvirtualenv
    hellodjango_venv/
        bin/
        include/
        lib/
```

But, do you remember the **three-tiered approach**? How can I achieve it?

I am quite sure hellodjango_rep/ later on will contain at least: .git, .gitignore and requirements.txt

## **Research:**

On the #django IRC channel, *Jacob Kaplan-Moss* answered:

> ...the Procfile needs to be at the top-level of your git repo...

*Neil Middleton*, Engineer at Heroku, answered this question "Procfile declares types -> (none) in Heroku" in SO:

> ...your Procfile needs to be in the root of your git repository that
>   is pushed to Heroku...

From Heroku Dev Center:

> ...Process types are declared via a file named Procfile placed in the
>   root of your app...

## **As a First Attempt:**

I move Procfile up one folder level.

```
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango oubiga$ cd ..
```

At the moment my Projects tree is:

```
~/Projects/    
    hellodjango_rep/ cwd
        Procfile
        hellodjango/
            manage.py
            hellodjango/
                __init__.py
                settings/
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
```

I start the process again:

```
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango_rep oubiga$ foreman start
```

I'll get [ImportError: No module named hellodjango.wsgi](http://pastebin.com/P2vDABez)

## **Debugging:**

The ImportError seems to come from `/Users/oubiga/Envs/hellodjango_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py`

```
def import_app(module):
    parts = module.split(":", 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        module, obj = module, "application"
    else:
        module, obj = parts[0], parts[1]

    try:
        __import__(module)  # <-- line 354
    except ImportError:
        if module.endswith(".py") and os.path.exists(module):
            raise ImportError("Failed to find application, did "
                "you mean '%s:%s'?" % (module.rsplit(".", 1)[0], obj))
        else:
            raise

...
```

No module named hellodjango.wsgi

## **As a Second Attempt:**

Procfile comes back at the previous level. Procfile and manage.py belong together again.

```
(hellodjango_venv)mac-pol:hellodjango_rep oubiga$ foreman start
```

I'll get `ERROR: Procfile does not exist.` It's quite obvious why it happens.

## **Hypothesis:**

From Django documentation:

> ...manage.py is automatically created in each Django project.
>   manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin.py that takes care of
>   two things for you before delegating to django-admin.py:
>   - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
>   - It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file...

I'm not sure if the problem is related to this.

## **So:**

**Is it possible to have a Procfile and a manage.py file in different folder level ?**
**What is wrong with this approach?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know its too late. You don't need to change anything. Put the `procfile` at top level. and run `gunicorn --chdir hellodjango hellodjango.wsgi`. It will work. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly I have to say, that I haven't done so wide research and have used Heroku about 3 times. But:

*(Your Seccond Attempt):*

Procfile really should be in the top level directory. If you move the Procfile deeper gunicorn can't find it.

*(Your First Attempt):*

And having your Procfile on the top level directory you should state path to wsgi. Which is not possible yet. So you shoud make __init__.py file in the first "hellodjango" directory, to mark it as "module". Then you shoud change the path in Procfile to: hellodjango.hellodjango.wsgi

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this using a *Two Scoops* layout, and my solution was to keep the standard layout (`Procfile` in `repository_root`, `manage.py` in `project_root`) and to make `Procfile` a script that changes directory into `project_root` before running gunicorn.

e.g., in `Procfile`:

```
web: sh -c 'cd ./mysite/ && exec gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -'
```

You could equally have `Procfile` call an external script:

```
web: bash scripts/heroku_run
```

I prefer this to adding additional module paths as it can mess up imports in `settings.py` and `urls.py`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot since I like to put the django root one level below repository root :)